# Extract names from PIV smartcard

Tags: openssl, redhat, smartcard, apdu, pkcs#11

I am trying to extract the following from a PIV Smartcard:

1. Subject Common Name
2. Certificate Subject Alt Name / Microsoft Principal Name

I am using RedHat 6 (eventually 7) and CoolKey as my PKCS11 module.

I need a way to extract this information via code without requiring the smartcard pin, be it from shell commands or a smartcard library. Currently I can get the Common Name by using the shell command 'pkcs11-tools --module  -T' so the Subject Alt Name is truly what I am after, but I would like to find a better way to get the Common Name if available.

I know this information is available without entering the pin as I can view it all in the included Smartcard Manager on RHEL (esc). I have a certificate chain of root, intermediate, and subordinate if that matters.

My thoughts are I have to extract the certificate from the card, verify that certificate with my local CAs, and then decrypt it. I have spent days reading documentation on APDUs, smartcards, and openssl and have gotten nowhere.

edit
view of RHEL smart card manager:
[image]

This is what the smart card viewer shows when you open the card and view the details. The Microsoft Principal Name is what I'm looking to extract from the card, as well as the "common name" which is displayed in the Hierarchy portion as well as other spots, shown by the red text.

I actually have since switched to using pkcs15-tool, as pkcs11-tool cutoff longer common names (you can see this in the title bar of the screenshot, same issue).
Output of: 'pkcs15-tool --list-info'

```
Using reader with a card: <reader name>
PKCS#15 Card [LASTNAME.FIRSTNAME.MIDDLENAME.12345678]:
        Version          : 0
        Serial number    : <big string>
        Manufacturer ID  : piv_II
        Flags            :
```

My current method is simply parsing the string in brackets as the common name and having users enter the Alt Name manually using the Redhat smartcard tool.

Comment: Looking at a [PIV specification](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-73-4) I'm unable to find the term *Subject Common Name*.

Comment: I guess he means the Subject CN of one or all certificates stored on the card.

Comment: Subject Common Name is what the Redhat smart card manager calls it, it's what shows up in the GUI when the card is inserted. It is listed as "token label" when running pkcs11-tool -T. Perhaps this is listed as "Name" on page 41 of the PIV specification? As for the alt name the only mention of it I see is on page 26.

Comment: The "token label" shown by pkcs11-tool can be extracted via `C_GetTokenInfo` (see [here](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/blob/4e0fef0e27cd832a571e876111b11b52b84e74c5/src/tools/pkcs11-tool.c#L1316)). Could you maybe edit your answer to include the output of pkcs11-tool and a screenshot of what the Redhat smartcard manager shows. I can provide more specific code examples for PKCS#11 once we have established what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the common name and UPN/Certificate Alt Name by using Java bouncycastle and the iaik pkcs11 wrapper.

```java
//path to .so library file
Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance(this.getProperties().getProperty("PKCS11_LIBRARY"));
pkcs11Module.initialize(null);
Slot[] slotsWithToken = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(Module.SlotRequirement.TOKEN_PRESENT);
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
for(Slot s : slotsWithToken)    {
    Session session = s.getToken().openSession(Token.SessionType.SERIAL_SESSION, Token.SessionReadWriteBehavior.RO_SESSION, null, null);
    session.findObjectsInit(new X509PublicKeyCertificate());
    Object[] objects = null;
    while((objects = session.findObjects(1)).length > 0)    {
        for(Object c : objects) {
            X509PublicKeyCertificate cert = (X509PublicKeyCertificate) c;
            byte[] certValue = cert.getValue().getByteArrayValue();
            Certificate cc = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certValue));
            if(cc instanceof X509Certificate)   {
                X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) cc;
                //COMMON NAME:
                String name = new X500Name(x509.getSubjectDN().getName()).getRDNs()[0].getFirst().getValue().toString();
                Collection<List<?>> altNames = x509.getSubjectAlternativeNames();
                for(List<?> list : altNames)    {
                    ASN1Sequence seq = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) list.get(1))).readObject());
                    ASN1TaggedObject obj = (ASN1TaggedObject) seq.getObjectAt(1);
                    //ALT NAME:
                    String upn = obj.getObject().toString();
                    upn = upn.substring(upn.lastIndexOf("]") + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The upn has '[0]' appended in front of it and I'm not sure why that is, so I operate on it to get rid of that.